# OS dev and where the boot sector is in qemu

Tags: qemu

I found this article about writing a simple OS:
https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf

In chapter 3 part 4 there it says that an "X" will be written to the boot sector at: 0x7c00 but, in qemu if you dump the memory you can see its not written to 0x7c00, its written to, 0x7fc8.

Why is this?
What bytes does qemu use for the boot sector?
https://gyazo.com/6dcfaeffea19dfbc6edffa22a1bf0c83

This is the code in the os-dev pdf:

```
mov ah , 0 x0e

mov bx , the_secret
add bx , 0 x7c00
mov al , [bx]
int 0 x10`

jmp $ ; Jump forever.

the_secret :
db "X "

; Padding and magic BIOS number.
times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
dw 0 xaa55
```

Comment: are you specifying [org 0x7c00] on your bootloader file?

Comment: just a code to find where the boot sector is.

Comment: as you can see in the picture the instructions aren't at 0x7c00 but, it does run without any problems.  It prints `X` like it should to a terminal

Comment: the way you get that is you goto the debugger thew telnet `-qmp tcp:localhost:4444,server --monitor stdio` and type in `dump-guest-memory`

Comment: I am on windows 10 Pro

Comment: Hello Whitequill, i think this may have to do with cs being set for you by qemu, since if you set it manually by doing a jmp 0:0x7c00 your program wont work anymore. Maybe Michael Petch can give us some light about this one.

Comment: @michael-petch: I feel that Tretorn has a good explanation. I'd just like to know if there is anything you feel could be added to this?